# New Safari users can't see the "Thanks, I will keep these tips in mind when asking" checkbox

Tags: bug, asking-questions, new-users

My friend "moyoteg" was trying to ask a question and couldn't figure out why he couldn't get past this screen:

[image: No check mark next to]

Notice that the checkbox is not really visible. He kept clicking "proceed" and it was taking him back to the page. He was using Safari 9.1.1 (11601.6.17). Can we get that styling fixed?

Comment: If he has any extensions/plugins installed, try disabling those and make sure it's not one of them.