# Can we have a filter to forbid a link-only question body?

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

Sometimes I can see questions which contains links and text within the link only,like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053192/how-can-a-value-from-a-boolean-condition-be-stored-in-a-variable-if-that-value-p

And I think link-only questions are almost surely not following the rules. Can we have a filter to avoid those type of questions submitting?

Comment: Yeah…that should have never gotten through, especially from a brand-new user. Seems [it's time to turn up the quality filter again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter).

Comment: related: [Disallow entire questions from being entirely bold, italic, ALL CAPS or linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286930/165773) "...why don't such questions go to [meta-tag:triage] queue?" (@CodyGray now that we've got Triage it can be done even without tweaking a filter)

Comment: @gnat I can reason that the difference is that this type of link-only question is definitely against the rules, while the entirely bold etc. etc. might still be salvageable.

Comment: @Walfrat: say what? All the filter has to do is (1) check if an entire question consists of one hyperlink, (2) if Yes, reject it. Why should the link be followed?

Comment: Will a filter really help, or will we instead just get: "I have the following question: <link given> "

Comment: Adding crap to queues requires humans to dig through it. I can't see why that would be more desirable than automatically filtering the crap out. The triage queue is useful in edge cases, where the content *might* be okay and needs a human reviewer. It is not necessary in obvious cases where a machine can be taught to do the filtering. A question that consists exclusively of a single line of link text is not an edge case in my opinion.

Comment: Here's some more (all deleted) http://stackoverflow.com/q/39307978/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/39928542/ http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b6b6d465-2683-438e-bc93-74fe0249a576/view-source http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47027df8-c688-4343-aea9-20095eb5104f/view-source http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5b17c093-0eec-401f-a4cf-3be24cf9c1fc/view-source

Comment: @RadLexus Misunderstood, though it was those kind of question  with a link then a quote block from the link, I see that in programmers.SE and it's refer generally to *discuss this ${blog}*.

Comment: I thought such filter already exists... wow.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm really surprised that there isn't a minimum length required to post the question as there is for comments. I could see the system automatically deleting them, but there should be some sort of floor to ensure at least _some_ attempt at an MVCE was made.

Comment: There *is* a minimum length for questions, @krillgar. But it's the *total* length of the unformatted question that gets counted, so turning it into a link fooled the filter in this case. Also, I don't know what the minimum length is set to currently, but it's probably not long enough.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, ok. I went to create a new question with just the letter "a" in the body. Without actually hitting Submit, I didn't see any message.

Comment: @CodyGray have you forgot that slogan when they introduced Triage and hiding triaged questions from regular readers? ["Take that, wall of cr@p"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/839601). My understanding is, Triage is for cases when there is a strong evidence that these don't belong (like link-only questions) and SE team just couldn't gain enough data to justify their outright automatic blocking. Triage reviewers seem to be primarily expected to confirm that question shouldn't be there and only rarely catch possible mistakes of automatic system

Comment: @HansOlsson - That's probably likely, the OP of the example question only made a link-only question because they couldn't post an *image*-only question, but if we make it hard to just post nonsense, maybe they'll go to the help center to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011047/how-many-threads-can-my-gpu-run-concurrently another recent egregious example

Comment: What if new users were forced to read the guidelines for questions before being able to ask one?

Comment: They already are, @J.Pichardo: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9710/159251

Comment: For sure they are encouraged but forced? Something like the Terms And Conditions

Comment: Yes, there's a required checkbox at the bottom: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329723/new-safari-users-cant-see-the-thanks-i-will-keep-these-tips-in-mind-when-aski

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can... I mean, we kinda already do; the same one we use for answers:

[image: Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 11]

Links are stripped prior to the length check, so if you don't have at least 30 characters worth of actual visible text then you'll be blocked. Now, 30 characters is a pitiful amount of text to require IMHO, but... That's a separate issue.

Now, this doesn't prevent you from writing a long-enough post and them making the whole thing into a link, but then again nothing stops you from making your entire post **bold** either, apart from the fact that both will likely be deleted in short order.

A quick check suggests there've only been 500-600 questions like this posted during the last year, with a bit over 80% deleted. Arguably then, this is just a way for askers to quickly let everyone know that they should just go straight for the close or downvote buttons.

I checked the logs for the person whose question you used as an example, btw: he actually made several attempts to post the code in the question prior to resorting to a link... But [ran face-first into the check that requires at least a nominal amount of explanatory text with the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107058/how-do-you-prevent-here-code-you-fix-questions). This suggests that blocking the link too would've likely just resulted in yet another work-around.

Comment: Could these filter grow nastier the more you hit them? ie. min quality score = 30 on first try, and .2 higher for each new attempt? I have to probably ask for actual numbers of how many people hits these filters first...

Comment: Problem is that even 100/100 just means "not egregiously bad". There's no way to identify "good" until real folks get to see it. Which is why repeated failures throw a question directly into Triage.

Comment: So in this specific instance, the filter arguably made the question *worse*? (Code dumps without explanation are really bad, of course, but a code dump is slightly better than a link, imo.)

Comment: Neither one would've been a very good question, @jpmc26. This got deleted faster, so...

Answer (score -2):

> Please read this link: http://www.example.com. My question is there.

This is what you can expect to happen from such a filter.

Comment: I believe the point of the proposal isn't getting rid of all link-only questions with no possibility of loopholes, but merely to eliminate those which can be unambiguously identified as such by a filter.

Comment: Upvote or downvote? That's a tricky one! Nice example, but I don't share your view.

Comment: "Other problems will result from this idea" isn't an argument against, unless either the idea doesn't help at all or the other problems are _worse_.

Comment: @duplode The point of the filter is to make fewer bad questions reach the site. I think such a filter is unlikely to improve the quality of questions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It may be very slightly worse, as we'll be changing something that is instantly recognizable as a bad question to something that is a bad question with filler text, potentially enough to make it slightly harder to recognize as one. Shog even checked the logs and came to the conclusion that's probably what would have happened here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Also, I think you misinterpreted this answer. (Potentially my fault for not explaining enough.) It isn't saying, "This other bad thing will happen if you do." It's saying, "Users will always find ways to post bad questions. Such a filter wouldn't solve the problem, and I doubt it would even reduce it very much."