# It should not be possible to post a question where the majority of the body is a link

Tags: feature-request, questions, quality-filter

A user posted the following question:

```
[My DateTimePicker doesn't show calander when am running it on safari,but when I run it on chrome,it works corrently][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14702.jpg
```

Is it possible to block this type of question via the quality filter?

Comment: While in principle I agree with you, would that same question be really improved if the link was set on only one word of the post?

Comment: It wouldn't, but I figure it's better to block blatant cases instead of blocking nothing at all.

Comment: How often does this really happen?

Comment: @Psubee2003 Not extremely often, but often enough to [annoy someone else enough to complain about it last year too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339277/7795130)

Comment: The block should really say "If the image is code, <...> If the image is problem statement, <...>" instead of just "You can't post <...>", if it's blocked.